# How to send to data or value from StatefulWidget subclass to StatelessWidget?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add some data from Stateful subclass to Stateless main

These are codes I wrote.

I know if I use Stateless widget only, these code will work properly.
But I want to some function that use Stateful widget later.

main.dart

```
children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Text(workout.title,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
                      child: Text(workout.count,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                    ),
                  ],
```

main_model.dart

```
Future add() async {
    final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('workoutlist');
    await collection.add({
      'title': newWorkoutText,
      'count': int.parse(newWorkoutDigit),
      'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
    });
```

add_page.dart

```
    class AddPage extends StatefulWidget {
    
      MainModel model;
    
      final String newWorkoutText;
      final String newWorkoutDigit;
    
      AddPage({Key key,this.model,this.newWorkoutText, this.newWorkoutDigit}): super(key : key);
    
      @override
      _AddPage createState() => _AddPage();
    
    }

  class _AddPage extends State<AddPage> {

  String newWorkoutText;
  String newWorkoutDigit;
  MainModel model;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MainModel>.value(

      value: model,

        
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
          TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    Text('{$widget.newWorkoutDigit}');
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: I added key in StatefulWidget but add() method error is happened again...